# Visual Studio 2015 and Gulp: get all files in all subdirectories

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sass, gulp

I am having a problem with Gulp not getting/referencing all the files it needs and erring. This was working for the previous dev who is no longer with us. The gulp method is erring with what appears to be reference errors. It doesn't seem to be able to 'see' any sub directories inside the Assets folder.

Here's the error:

```
[08:47:38] Using gulpfile C:\Development...\Gulpfile.js
[08:47:38] Starting 'icons'...
[08:47:38] Finished 'icons' after 48 ms
[08:47:38] Starting 'sass'...
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error: Assets\sass\styles.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap
   Parent style sheet: C:/Development/***... on line 5 of     Assets/sass/styles.scss
>> @import 'bootstrap';
```

Here is my relevant gulp script:

```
gulp.task('sass', ['icons'], function() {
return gulp.src('./Assets/sass/styles.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({
        includePaths: [
        'bower_components/bootstrap/scss',
        'bower_components/font-awesome/scss',
        'bower_components/bootstrap4-chosen'
        ]
    }))
    .pipe(concat('styles.css'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/css'))
    .pipe(browserSyncStream());
});
```

styles.scss:

```
// Base vendors and variables
@import 'font-awesome';
@import 'variables';
@import 'bootstrap';

// Mixins, utilities and base styles
@import 'mixins';
@import 'utilities';
@import 'base';
```

Here's the folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

Changing the @import in styles.scss to:

```
@import '../../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

Get's me a different error:

```
> Error: Undefined variable: "$font-size-lg".
    on line 38 of Assets/sass/_layout.scss
>>      font-size: $font-size-lg;
```

Seems like there are more references missing here... and I think that the gulp scripting is not getting all files via recursively searching all subfolders... how do I finesse it to do that? Or is there something else missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your `sass` task. Tried it. Works.

My guess is that your colleague was using a development version of the upcoming [bootstrap 4.0.0](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v4.0.0-alpha.2) but you have bootstrap 3.x installed. The current [bootstrap 3.3.6](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v3.3.6) does not have an `scss` folder since it still uses `less`. If you simply `bower install bootstrap` you get 3.3.6.

Make sure you have the following in your `bower.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.2"
}
```

Or install bootstrap 4.0.0 directly using:

```
bower install bootstrap#4.0.0-alpha.2
```

Comment: You brought me around to the right answer via 'bower install bootstrap'... somehow, bower wasn't installed... but it WAS installed... so strange... I could right click my bower folder and 'manage bower packages' but when I tried anything in the 'package manager console' with 'bower... anything' it bombed saying bower wasn't installed... Installed bower, then installed bootstrap and it got by that error. The next error led me to reordering my @includes so the 'variables' and 'base' came first. That seemed to be the final fix.